# Prototype, listening to a change in radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, prototypejs

I've been searching for a solution for days for this, so I hope you can help.

I'm using custom form elements by Ryan Fait, which lets you style checkboxes, and radio buttons etc.

The only problem is I can't use onClick events anymore, since the actual box gets overwritten with a  with the images for the custom radio elements.

The javascript does actually change the radio buttons, but I can't seem to find a way to detect changes..

Currently, I've tried this:

```
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    $('startquestion').observe('change', set_startanswer(this.value));  
});
```

HTML:

```
    <p>
<input type="radio" class="styled" name="startanswer" id="startquestion" value="'.$startq['id'].'" onclick="if (this.checked == true) { set_startanswer(this.value); }"'.$s.'> <span id="startanswertext'.$startq['id'].'">'.$startq['question'].'</span>
    </p>
```

Though, it doesn't seem to be working.

Can anyone help me?

Cheers!
Danny

Comment: [***What have you tried?***](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) For instance, are we to assume you've tried the `change` event? If you have, and it's not being fired, can I respectfully suggest using another mechanism for styling radio buttons and checkboxes?

Comment: Yes, I have. Though I'm new to Prototype (JS in general, really).
I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to observe the change event on Radio list :

```
Form.getInputs('form','radio','radio_name').find(function(radio){

            Event.observe(radio, 'change', function() {

              //do whatever on this change

            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The script you are using hides the original checkboxes and displays some custom graphics above. It registers the clicks on the graphics and sets the hidden checkbox accordingly - but programmatically setting the checkbox states won't fire change events.

To work around this issue you can probably explicitly catch clicks on the custom graphics (the script creates a wrapping `p` element). Using your code lines from above:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    var startquestionElement = $('startquestion');
    var startquestionState = startquestionElement.checked;
    startquestionElement.up().observe('click', function() {
        if (startquestionElement.checked != startquestionState) {
            startquestionState = startquestionElement.checked;
            set_startanswer(startquestionElement.value); // are you sure you want to use the element's value and not it's checked state?
        }
    });  
});
```

Another alternative would be to globally observe the checkbox state by using a timer and checking e.g. every 100 ms:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    var startquestionElement = $('startquestion');
    var startquestionState = startquestionElement.checked;
    var observingInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if (startquestionElement.checked != startquestionState) {
            // If you want to stop observing after the checkbox has changed it's state once,
            // uncomment the following line:
            // clearInterval(observingInterval);
            startquestionState = startquestionElement.checked;
            set_startanswer(startquestionElement.value); // are you sure you want to use the element's value and not it's checked state?
        }
    }, 100);  
});
```

You could use the latter version to check for multiple checkboxes in one observing function call.

Answer (score 0):

You can include [event.simulate.js](https://raw.github.com/kangax/protolicious/master/event.simulate.js) from [protolicious](https://github.com/kangax/protolicious) and then fire a native click event on the image element directly.

```
$('id_of_button').simulate('click');
```